# USB Device cannot be opened sometimes

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I get a list of paths of all available devices with a specific GUID using 
`SetupDiGetClassDevs()`, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()` and `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()`. This works quite well.

Then i try to open the USB device using the device path acquired:

```
// open this device
HANDLE hUsbDevice = CreateFile(oDevicePath, 
                               GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,  
                               0/*FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE*/, 
                               NULL, 
                               OPEN_EXISTING, 
                               FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                               NULL);
```

<del>This works always if the device was not plugged in before application start and if the device has been removed and plugged in after a few seconds.</del>

<del>If the device has already been plugged in at application start and has not been removed and plugged in again, the returned handle is always `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.</del>

<del>How can i open the device even if it was connected before?</del>

I didn't detect any pattern yet to determine when this succeeds. What can i do (in software) to always be able to open this device?

Thank you for your help!

---

---

More information:

A devicePath that can be opened:
`\\?\usb#vid_cantTell&pid_0200#6&3ab10970&0&2#{that_proprietary_guid}`

A device Path that can't be opened:
`\\?\usb#vid_cantTell&pid_0200#6&3ab10970&0&2#{that_proprietary_guid}`

Result of `GetLastError()`: 31 (0x1F) -> Some Driver Problem i guess

Comment: Right after the call to `CreateFile` fails, you should run `GetLastError` so we can get more information.  Also, for debugging, you should print `oDevicePath` right before calling `CreateFile` and give us some examples of paths that work and paths that do not work.

Comment: Could be a basic USB communication error. Try a different USB port and cable.

Comment: the third cable did the trick ... thanks